# Laravel binding params

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am using below query to get results of 4 id's, but it shows only one result

```
$id = array(6,7,8,9);      
        $params = array(
            'connection' => 'redis',
            'id' => implode(',',$id)
        );

        $result =  DB::select(
            DB::raw("
                SELECT 
                    * 
                FROM 
                    failed_jobs 
                WHERE 
                    id IN (:id) AND 
                    connection = :connection
            "), $params);
```

Comment: manual binding for an array should be like `"WHERE IN (:id1, :id2, :id3)"` with the params `['id1'=>6, 'id2'=>7, 'id3'=>8]` which you have to work around to handle the generation of the prepared statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to go about it is to use the query builder instead. This is much cleaner since it provides the `whereIn` clause:

```
$id = array(6,7,8,9);

$result = DB::table('failed_jobs')
    ->where('connection', 'redis')
    ->whereIn('id', $id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Cant we achieve result in my query using colon

Comment: Need to know why its showing only one result

Comment: Not really, because of the `in` clause. Question marks would be easier, but you cannot implode your array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition has more information on that.